# slurm: Where should the source code of Slurm job along with its dependent file should be stored?

Tags: slurm

**[Q]** Size of my source code is 10 MB but it depends on a 1GB file. I just wonder about where should the source code of Slurm job along with its dependent file should be stored? If its on hands of the admin, which approach is recommended to do? Is there any documentation about this?

- Case1: Storing on controller's local storage? (If yes, does compute note captures the source code into its local storage?)
- Case2: Storing on compute node's local storage?
- Case3: Storing on a shared memory where all compute nodes and controller could have a access?

For example, I have a controller and 10 computes nodes running behind it.

(`case-1`) If job's source code is stored on controller's storage, when we submit the job through `sbatch`, does source code transferred into compute node and when job updates any file which will written back to the controller's local storage? , so there should be file transfer in between controller and compute node, which might have a high I/O usage.

(`case-2`) if there are multiple compute nodes, since when I submit my job they selected dynamically, should I write source code into all of their local storage?

(`case-3`), should all compute nodes have fast access to the shared memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compute cluster typically has several filesystems (storage places to store files) accessible by the users, with distinct scopes and purposes. For instance:

- a 'home' filesystem, shared by all compute nodes, built for stability (backups, high-availability, etc.) where users can store their code, configuration files, etc.
- a 'scratch' filesystem, shared by all compute nodes, built for performances rather than stability (parallel filesystem, no backup etc.)
- a 'TMP' filesystem, distinct for all nodes, used for temporary files, and typical cleaned after each job

With a 10-node cluster and one controller, you should at minima export storage from the controller to the compute nodes with [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System). You can store all files in there. If the jobs only read the data sequentially at the beginning, then this should be ok.

If the job read the data randomly throughout the job, you can duplicate the data onto the local disks of the compute nodes. Alternatively, you can install a [BeeGFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeeGFS) filesystem on the compute nodes to gather all disks into one single system, so that the files are accessible from all nodes and configure it with duplication for each node.

If the jobs write a lot of data randomly during their lifetime, they should write to local node storage and then copy back onto the home filesystem at the end of the job.